# Error: "[ngModel:datefmt] Expected `08:00:00` to be a date

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, momentjs

I am working on mvc application using angularJs , i have an issue on html input type time i cannot get the time from database and bind it with input type time .

> This is error message on debug angularjs

`Error: "[ngModel:datefmt] Expected`08:00:00`to be a date 
Error: "[ngModel:datefmt] Expected`17:00:00`to be a date`

> this is the html

```
       <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label"> Time From</label>
           <input ng-model="Branch_TimeFrom" type="time" name="Branch_TimeFrom">                         
       </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label"> Time To</label>
           <input ng-model="Branch_TimeTo" type="time" name="Branch_TimeTo">                         
       </div>
```

**APP.JS**

```html
 //get single record by ID
    $scope.getForUpdate = function (Branch) {
        debugger
        $scope.Branch_ID = Branch.Branch_ID;
        $scope.Branch_Name = Branch.Branch_Name;
        $scope.Branch_Address = Branch.Branch_Address;
        $scope.Branch_email = Branch.Branch_email;
        $scope.Branch_Notes = Branch.Branch_Notes;
        $scope.Branch_TimeFrom = moment(Branch.Branch_TimeFrom).format('HH:mm:ss');
        $scope.Branch_TimeTo = moment(Branch.Branch_TimeTo).format('HH:mm:ss');
        $scope.Branch_Manager = Branch.Branch_Manager;
        $scope.Branch_Phone = Branch.Branch_Phone;
        $scope.saturday = Branch.saturday;
    };
```

> this is the result on debug code,my question is how to display time to input type time i tried alot of solutions but did't fix it so far .
>   any advice

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i just changed my code to that solved my issue

```
 $scope.getForUpdate = function (Branch) {
    debugger
    $scope.Branch_ID = Branch.Branch_ID;
    $scope.Branch_Name = Branch.Branch_Name;
    $scope.Branch_Address = Branch.Branch_Address;
    $scope.Branch_email = Branch.Branch_email;
    $scope.Branch_Notes = Branch.Branch_Notes;
    $scope.Branch_TimeFrom = new Date(moment(Branch.Branch_TimeFrom));
    $scope.Branch_TimeTo = new Date(moment(Branch.Branch_TimeTo)); 
    $scope.Branch_Manager = Branch.Branch_Manager;
    $scope.Branch_Phone = Branch.Branch_Phone;
    $scope.saturday = Branch.saturday;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When using input type time in editable form, if the control shows seconds and millisecond to enter it becomes bit nasty. Also entering time in millisecond in a form by user seems bit odd, unless otherwise its a requirement.

We can write a common method to remove the second and millisecond part in the controller.

```
getFormatDate = function (val) { // assuming val is date like "/Date(946673340000)/"
 if (val != undefined) {
    date = new Date(val.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); // creating a date object from val
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
   date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
 }
}
```